# Shell script - awk extract block from file into array

Tags: arrays, bash, shell, awk, vagrant

I'm currently writing a shell script that reads a Vagrantfile and bootstraps it (in a nutshell ;) )

But I'm hitting a wall with the following piece of code:

```
TEST=()
while read result; do
  TEST+=(`echo ${result}`)
done <<< `awk '/config.vm.define[ \s]\"[a-z]*\"[ \s]do[ \s]\|[a-zA-Z_]*\|/, /end/ { print }' Vagrantfile`

echo "${TEST[1]}"
```

When I pass a Vagrantfile into this awk pattern regex with two machines defined (config.vm.define) in it they are found.

The output

```
config.vm.define "web" do |web|

web.vm.box       = "CentOs"
web.vm.box_url   = "http://developer.nrel.gov/downloads/vagrant-boxes/CentOS-6.4-x86_64-v20130731.box"
web.vm.hostname  = 'dev.local'

web.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 90, host: 9090
web.vm.network :private_network, ip: "22.22.22.11"

web.vm.provision :puppet do |puppet|
  puppet.manifests_path = "puppet/manifests"
  puppet.manifest_file  = "web.pp"
  puppet.module_path    = "puppet/modules"
  puppet.options        = ["--verbose", "--hiera_config /vagrant/hiera.yaml", "--parser future"]
end
config.vm.define "db" do |db_mysql|

db_mysql.vm.box       = "CentOs"
db_mysql.vm.box_url   = "http://developer.nrel.gov/downloads/vagrant-boxes/CentOS-6.4-x86_64-v20130731.box"
db_mysql.vm.hostname  = 'db.mysql.local'

db_mysql.vm.network :private_network, ip: "22.22.22.22"
db_mysql.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 3306, host: 3306

db_mysql.vm.provision :puppet do |puppet|
  puppet.manifests_path = "puppet/manifests"
  puppet.manifest_file = "db.pp"
  puppet.module_path = "puppet/modules"
  puppet.options = ["--verbose", "--hiera_config /vagrant/hiera.yaml", "--parser future"]
end
```

But I can't seem to pass them into a array nicely. What I want is that the TEST array contains two indexes with the machine config.vm.define block as their corresponding values.

E.g.

```
TEST[0] = 'config.vm.define "web" do |web|

.... [REST OF THE BLOCK CONTENT] ...

end'

TEST[1] = 'config.vm.define "db" do |db_mysql|

.... [REST OF THE BLOCK CONTENT] ...

end'
```

The output `echo "${TEST[1]}"` is `nothing`. `echo "${TEST[0]}"` returns the whole block as plotted above.

I played with IFS / RS / FS but I can't seem to get the output I want.

Comment: What is the exact output of the `awk` command by itself? And what is the result of `echo "${TEST[1]}"` in your example?

Comment: Are there newline characters within each `config.vm.define` block?

Comment: @grebneke updated the question with output

And yes there are newlines in it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution might be to write the two blocks to two separate files (`blk1` and `blk2`) as:

```
awk '
  /config.vm.define[[:space:]]\"[a-z]*\"[[:space:]]do[[:space:]]\|[a-zA-Z_]*\|/{f=1; i++}
  f{print $0 > "blk"i}
  /end/ {f=0}' Vagrantfile
```

and then later read these two files into the bash array as

```
IFS= TEST=( $(cat <"blk1") $(cat <"blk2") )
```

**Note:**

- The regex `\s` seems to work only for the latest version of `gawk` (Works with version 4.1, but not version 3.1.8.
- For `gawk` version 3.1.8, use `[[:space:]]` instead.
- For `gawk` version 4.1, the regex `\s` does not work inside brackets `[\s]`. Use either `config.vm.define[[:space:]]` or `config.vm.define\s`..

**Update**

An alternative could be to insert an artificial separator between the blocks, for instance the string `@@@`. Then you could do

```
IFS= TEST=()
while IFS= read -r -d '@' line ; do
    TEST+=($line)
done < <(awk '
  /config.vm.define[[:space:]]\"[a-z]*\"[[:space:]]do[[:space:]]\|[a-zA-Z_]*\|/{f=1; i++}
  f{print }
  /end/ {f=0; print "@@@"}' Vagrantfile)
```

Comment: Thanks I'll give it a shot. I'll let you know!

Comment: Gave it a try and it works. Minor error in your first solution. I needed to wrap the variable filename in parentheses. Otherwise it gave an error. This way it gets properly concatenated

`awk 
'/config.vm.define[[:space:]]\"[a-z]*\"[[:space:]]do[[:space:]]\|[a-zA-Z_]*\|/ {f=1; i++} 
f{print $0 > ("block"i)} 
/end/ {f=0}' Vagrantfile`